# ORA-00904 : invalid identifier error when updating

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

**My Global Class :**

```
class Global
{
    public static OleDbDataAdapter adapter;

    public static DataTable dt;
}
```

The procedure I'm using to fill my `DataGridView` :

```
    OleDbConnection connection;

    OleDbCommandBuilder builder;

    void gridfill()
    {

        connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=XXX;" 
                                       + "user id=XXX;password=XXX;"
                                       + "persist security info=false;");


        Global.adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select \"Id\", \"UserComputer\", \"GuralID\", \"Type\", \"CreatedOn\", \"State\" from COMPUTERS", connection);

        builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(Global.adapter);

        Global.dt = new DataTable();

        Global.adapter.Fill(Global.dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = Global.dt;

        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;

    }
```

The procedure I'm using to update a field in a row in my Oracle DB :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == "New")
            {
                Global.dt.Rows[rowId]["State"] = 0;
            }
            else if (comboBox1.Text == "Old")
            {
                Global.dt.Rows[rowId]["State"] = 1;
            }
            else if (comboBox1.Text == "Junk")
            {
                Global.dt.Rows[rowId]["State"] = 2;
            }
            Global.adapter.Update(Global.dt);
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When I run, I get my `DataGridView` filled. That part is okay. And then I double click on a row and another form shows up. That form gets values of the selected row. There's an update button on it. I use it to change the value of a field of the selected row. 3rd code I shared with you is the one to do that. But I get ORA-00904: "STATE" invalid identifier.

I debugged it. The error comes in this line :

```
Global.adapter.Update(Global.dt);
```

**TIPS:**

Tables are actually created by ORM classes.

As I know this is something about double quotes.

```
Ex : 'Select State from COMPUTERS' does not work but 'Select "State" from COMPUTERS' does.
```

I used '\' prefix in my `SQL` query after having the same issue when filling `DataGridView`. The problem solved.

But I cannot use it when trying to assign a new value to the field. And I need a way to do that.

I guess the problem is here :

```
Global.dt.Rows[rowId]["State"] = 0;
```

What can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the [`QuotePrefix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.quoteprefix.aspx) and [`QuoteSuffix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.quotesuffix.aspx) on your `OleDbCommandBuilder` object to `"`.

By default, the `OleDbCommandBuilder` doesn't know what quotation system the database system it's talking to uses.

Comment: builder.QuotePrefix = "\"";

builder.QuoteSuffix = "\"";